# Connecting to a large number of concurrent streaming endpoints in Python

Tags: python, http, streaming, endpoint

I have been trying to connect to a large number (somewhere in the thousands) of streaming http endpoints at the same time using a pycurl multi object. This seems to work fine when I have a small number of streams, however when I attempt to connect a larger number of endpoints, there is a large delay in setup time and sometimes the endpoints don't seem to read in whole message. All of the endpoints send a json object around every 5 seconds which I then need to process. My current code looks like this while changing some of the variable names to be a bit more generic.

```
m = pycurl.CurlMulti()

for connection_num in range(1, num_connections):
    conn = pycurl.Curl()
    conn_fuel.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'url/{}'.format(connection_num))
    conn_fuel.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, on_receive_foo)
    m.add_handle(conn)

while 1:
    ret, num_handles = m.perform()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

I have tried to set the MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS using setopt like this in case that is the problem, but that returns an error saying that attribute does not exist.

```
m.setopt(pycurl.M_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS, 6000)
```

Is there a faster or better way to receive the connections with a pycurl multi object or am I wasting my time and should look somewhere else?

I am still very new to connections and especially new to streaming and the like so I am sorry if there is an obvious answer.